# Exporting available time from calendars to Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, export

Any way to export ONLY available time from Outlook calendars to Excel?

Although helpful, I was able to export BUSY and TENTATIVE time/dates to Excel by following steps in this site (I followed directions from this site to export to Excel--but wanted to know if I can only export available time (I know...picky, picky).

Comment: Can you link to the question whose process you followed or repost it here? It would be easier to start with that and suggest changes you can make. It would be helpful to see both the process and results.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out; if I cannot find it and post here by Monday--please disregard. Appreciate your time.